# Getting error invalid assignment left-hand side

Tags: jquery

i am suing a function in which i try to limit textarea length but on one condition i am getting the above mentioned error. Please tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
 function limitTextArea(element, limit) {

    var $textArea = $(element);    
    ($textArea).keypress(function(event){

        if ($textArea.val().length == limit) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if ($textArea.val().length > limit) {

            // Maximum exceeded
            $textArea.val() = $textArea.val().substr(0, limit);
        }

    }); //end of keypress

} //end of function()
```

The line

```
$textArea.val() = $textArea.val().substr(0, limit);
```

give me error that `invalid assignment left-hand side`. Why i am getting that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$textArea.val()` is a function so you don't want to assign a string to it.

The following code will assign the value to $textArea:

```
$textArea.val($textArea.val().substr(0, limit));
```